# Tabulator.js - Responsive and Persistent configuration

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I try to use [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) table inside a new project.

From the docs, we can use a [Responsive](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/layout#responsive-collapse) layout to hide columns that do not fit in the browser. When I resize the window, columns are placed below each line, in a container, as expected.

But when I try to [persist columns](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/persist#columns) on Session Storage, and reload the page, all colunms in that container are not re-displayed. They are hidden because all of them contain `visible:false`.

There is a code to reproduce the problem :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tabulator Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.0/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example-table"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.0/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var tabledata = [
                {field_001:"value-001-1", field_002:"value-002-1", field_003:"value-003-1", field_004:"value-004-", field_005:"value-005-1", field_006:"value-006-1", field_007:"value-007-1", field_008:"value-008-1", field_009:"value-009-1", field_010:"value-010-1", field_011:"value-011-1", field_012:"value-012-1", field_013:"value-013-1", field_014:"value-014-1", field_015:"value-015-1", field_016:"value-016-1", field_017:"value-017-1", field_018:"value-018-1", field_019:"value-019-1", field_020:"value-020-1"},
                {field_001:"value-001-2", field_002:"value-002-2", field_003:"value-003-2", field_004:"value-004-2", field_005:"value-005-2", field_006:"value-006-2", field_007:"value-007-2", field_008:"value-008-2", field_009:"value-009-2", field_010:"value-010-2", field_011:"value-011-2", field_012:"value-012-2", field_013:"value-013-2", field_014:"value-014-2", field_015:"value-015-2", field_016:"value-016-2", field_017:"value-017-2", field_018:"value-018-2", field_019:"value-019-2", field_020:"value-020-2"},
                {field_001:"value-001-3", field_002:"value-002-3", field_003:"value-003-3", field_004:"value-004-3", field_005:"value-005-3", field_006:"value-006-3", field_007:"value-007-3", field_008:"value-008-3", field_009:"value-009-3", field_010:"value-010-3", field_011:"value-011-3", field_012:"value-012-3", field_013:"value-013-3", field_014:"value-014-3", field_015:"value-015-3", field_016:"value-016-3", field_017:"value-017-3", field_018:"value-018-3", field_019:"value-019-3", field_020:"value-020-3"},
                {field_001:"value-001-4", field_002:"value-002-4", field_003:"value-003-4", field_004:"value-004-4", field_005:"value-005-4", field_006:"value-006-4", field_007:"value-007-4", field_008:"value-008-4", field_009:"value-009-4", field_010:"value-010-4", field_011:"value-011-4", field_012:"value-012-4", field_013:"value-013-4", field_014:"value-014-4", field_015:"value-015-4", field_016:"value-016-4", field_017:"value-017-4", field_018:"value-018-4", field_019:"value-019-4", field_020:"value-020-4"},
            ];
            var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
                responsiveLayout:"collapse",
                responsiveLayoutCollapseStartOpen:false,
                layout:"fitColumns", 
                movableColumns: true,
                resizableColumnFit:true,
                persistence:{
                    columns:true
                },
                data:tabledata,
                columns:[ 
                    {formatter:"responsiveCollapse", hozAlign:"center", resizable:false, headerSort:false, download:false},
                    {title:"001", field:"field_001", visible:true},
                    {title:"002", field:"field_002", visible:true},
                    {title:"003", field:"field_003", visible:true},
                    {title:"004", field:"field_004", visible:true},
                    {title:"005", field:"field_005", visible:true},
                    {title:"006", field:"field_006", visible:true},
                    {title:"007", field:"field_007", visible:true},
                    {title:"008", field:"field_008", visible:true},
                    {title:"009", field:"field_009", visible:true},
                    {title:"010", field:"field_010", visible:true},
                    {title:"011", field:"field_011", visible:true},
                    {title:"012", field:"field_012", visible:true},
                    {title:"013", field:"field_013", visible:true},
                    {title:"014", field:"field_014", visible:true},
                    {title:"015", field:"field_015", visible:true},
                    {title:"016", field:"field_016", visible:true},
                    {title:"017", field:"field_017", visible:true},
                    {title:"018", field:"field_018", visible:true},
                    {title:"019", field:"field_019", visible:true},
                    {title:"020", field:"field_020", visible:true}
                ],
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a JsFiddle to test : [Tabulator Responsive and Persistence test](https://jsfiddle.net/ogay0uxn/)

Is there a another way to do this?